# Format text for custom search suggestions provided in a cursor from a content provider

Tags: android, search

I have a search box setup that is provided with custom search suggestions through a ContentProvider. These suggestions are handled through the Android search suggestions API, collected by calling a `Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)` method. When suggestions are returned in the cursor they are displayed in a list below the search box.

My problem is that I want to make a substring in each search suggestion bold. I have put HTML bold tags `<b>` and `</b>` around these substrings. However, even through I add `Html.fromHtml(stringWithBoldTags)` to the Cursor that is returned (a `MatrixCursor`), the text is all displayed as plain text.

I was wondering if there was a way of just making some text bold with the search suggestions API. I don't want to completely restyle the search suggestions, so it seems so over the top to implement my own search suggestions API just for this small change.

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    List<String> suggestions = getSuggestions(searchTerm);

    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, 
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, 
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA, 
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY } );
    for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); ++i) {
        String suggestion = suggestions.get(i);
        Object[] row = { Integer.toString(i), 
                         Html.fromHtml(makeSubstringBold(suggestion, searchTerm)),
                         suggestion, suggestion };
        cursor.addRow(row);
    }
    return cursor;
}

private List<String> getSuggestions(String searchTerm) {
    // Return a list of suggestions for the searchTerm
}

private String makeSubstringBold(String fullString, String substring) {
    // Find substring in fullString and add HTML bold tags either side of it
}
```

If anyone knows of any way that you can make the search suggestions API obey the bold tags returned in the cursor, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: bold tags? in Android? I'm new myself but I dont think it's possible to use html just xml. What you must do is make the textview text bold

Comment: The Html.fromHtml works just fine in other situations. It returns a Spanned object, which the TextView text can be set to and you can make certain characters in the string bold. The problem I have is that using the search suggestion API you just return a Cursor of data. So as far as I am aware I have no control over the actual ListView the suggestions are shown in. I was asking if anyone knew if you could.